# class member definition in java

Tags: java

I recently encountered this phrase:

```
"Class A has class member int a"
```

Probably obvious but this sentence just means `a` is an `int` defined in `class A`, right?

And another thing, for example `a` is defined under a method in `class A`. is it still
a class member?
I haven't found a clear definition of class member, I looked [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):
but it wasn't very helpful.

Thank's in advance for the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class member is another way of calling static members.

```
class A {
    int a; //instance variable
    static int b; //class variable
    public void c() {
        int d; //local variable
    }
}
```

Comment: b is same through all instances but a is different and d sometimes exists sometimes not ?

Comment: Ok, so basically on my example they say class A with a int static?

Comment: @Raeldrouianov Yes that's it.

Answer (score 1):

[In same  docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

> Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class variables
>
> Class variables are referenced by the class name itself, as in

```
Bicycle.numberOfBicycles
```

> This makes it clear that they are class variables.

Answer (score 1):

class member is not just a variable of the class. they can be accessed using the class name. That means they are static variable of that class.

The document mentioned it clearly.

```
public class Bicycle {

private int cadence;
private int gear;
private int speed;

// add an instance variable for the object ID
private int id;

// add a class variable for the
// number of Bicycle objects instantiated
private static int numberOfBicycles = 0;

 ...
}
```

in the above code numberOfBicycles  is a class member. It can be accessed  using

```
Bicycle.numberOfBicycles
```

And variables inside methods can't access like that. so  they can't be class members. variables declared inside a method are local variables and belong to that method. So you can call them final, but not static or public or protected or private.

Answer (score 0):

In the docs [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) you have mentiond, its clear in the first line (after heading) that

```
In this section, we discuss the use of the static keyword to create fields and methods that belong to the class, rather than to an instance of the class.
```

So it means that `static` keyword is used to create class fields and methods(i.e.class members).
So in your case,

```
class A{
    int a;
    public void methodA(){
        int a;//inner a
    }

}
```

What you have asked is that is `int a` inside methodA() still a class member?

Answer is **no**: since it is not preceded by static keyword.If you try to use static keyword as:

```
class A{
    int a;
    public void methodA(){
        static int a;//inner a will cause compile time error
    }

}
```

You will get compile time error.
Hope that helped!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Variable in Java is a data container(memory) that stores the data values during Java program execution.There are 3 types of variables in java.
They are local variables,instance variables,static variables.
local variables - declared within the body of a method..
instance variables - declared inside the class but not inside the method,to access these variables you need to create an object
static - memory allocated only once..directly accessible and its not object specific
Static variables defined at global scope of the class and so they also refereed as class member.for example

```
 public class TypesofVar {
   int a = 10; // instance variables
   static int c = 30; // static variables
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int b = 20; // local variable
     System.out.println(c);
     System.out.println(b);
     TypesofVar obj = new TypesofVar();
     System.out.println(obj.a);
   }
 }
```

What you have asked is that is int a inside methodA() still a class member?
NO because it is not preceded by static keyword